# Using grep and awk to search and print the output to new file

Tags: awk, grep

I have 100 files and want to search a specific word in the first column of each file and print the content of all columns from this word to a new file
I tried this code but doesn't work well it prints only the content of one file not all:

```
ls -t *.txt > Filelist.tmp
cat Filelist.tmp | while read line do; grep "searchword" | awk '{print $0}' > outputfile.txt; done
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what you want:

```
$ awk '$1~/searchword/' *.txt >> output
```

This compares the first field against `searchword` and appends the line to `output` if it matches. The default field separator with `awk` is whitespace.

The main problem with your attempt is you are overwriting `>` the file evertime, you want to be using append `>>`.

Comment: Great, you now need to [accept this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) by clicking the tick mark next to it to show this question is solved.